# Spring Web MVC Tiles Attribute 'header' not found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying to use tiles library in my spring MVC project.

wel-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smart" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme1/" />

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
            </value>
        </property> 
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="login" template="/view/home.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/view/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

home.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<html>
<head>
    <Title>Home</Title>
</head>
<body>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</body>
</html>
```

ProfilePage.java

```
@Controller
public class ProfilePage {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showPost(@ModelAttribute("commentForm") Post post, ModelMap model, HttpSession session)
    {
             return new ModelAndView("home", model);
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginWorld(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("commentForm") Post post, @ModelAttribute("loginForm") Employee employee, HttpSession session, BindingResult errorResult){

             // Logic

                model.addAttribute("result", result);
        return new ModelAndView(returnPage, model);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'header' not found.
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'header' not found.
    org.apache.tiles.template.DefaultAttributeResolver.computeAttribute(DefaultAttributeResolver.java:50)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.resolveAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:165)
    org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.execute(InsertAttributeModel.java:121)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:299)
    org.apache.jsp.view.home_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(home_jsp.java:379)
    org.apache.jsp.view.home_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(home_jsp.java:318)
    org.apache.jsp.view.home_jsp._jspService(home_jsp.java:147)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I am not getting why this error is coming!!

Comment: where does 'header.jsp' resides in your project(location).

Comment: `header.jsp` is present in the same folder i.e. `view` folder

Comment: is the 'view' folder inside 'WEB-INF'?

Comment: No, it is inside `WebContent` directory. `tiles.xml` is present in `WEB-INF`

Comment: Shouldn't It be inside WEB-INF?

Comment: before using `tiles.xml`, the project was working fine. Also I have given the proper path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all move your 'view' folder to the 'WEB-INF' directory and change the following mappings

try changing the below mapping in your tiles.xml

```
<definition name="login" template="/view/home.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/view/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="" />
</definition>
```

to the following

```
<definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/view/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="" />
</definition>


<definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp" />
</definition>
```

> The return value of every controller will be mapped with each tiles
>   definition which is associated with jsp to render as body in template.
>   This is why we need to add mapping for 'home'.

create template.jsp as follows

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<html>
<head>
    <Title>template</Title>
</head>
<body>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</body>
</html>
```

then your home.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>

<html>
<head>
    <Title>Home</Title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

here in home.jsp you don't need to insert attribute 'header'. tiles will do this for you.

And also delete the InternalResourceViewResolver

Comment: Are you deploying this as war in server. Then please check to see the files are there in the folder(inside 'WEB-NF/view/').

Comment: I am using eclipse to run the project

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check to see if it works.

Comment: Finally, it worked, Thanks for your solution. I also had to removed `InternalResourceViewResolver` class from my servlet file!!

Answer (score 1):

Change your tiles as below :

```
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/view/mainTemplate.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/header.jsp"></put-attribute>      
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
<definition extends="base.definition" name="home">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Home Page"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/home.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

Create /WEB-INF/view/mainTemplate.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="header">
     <!-- Header Tiles -->
     <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
  </div>


  <div id="section">
     <!-- Body Tiles -->
     <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
     <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
  </div>
  <!-- footer Tiles -->    
</body>
</html>
```

Then create your /WEB-INF/view/home.jsp. Content of home.jsp will automatically come in body of mainTemplate.jsp